# Mapping User.Identity in .NET MVC app to active directory user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing a .NET MVC 5 app which is on an intranet, uses Windows Authentication and needs to query Active Directory to see what groups are available and then check if a user is in that role.

The source of group and user names will be active directory. I then need to check identity and membership using .NET Identity. I'm not sure what fields map to what.

Fields of interest in AD seem to be:

- **SamAccountName:** I think this is the username that I get from User.Identity, but the docs say that this property is:
  *The logon name used to support clients and servers running earlier versions of the operating system, such as Windows NT 4.0, Windows 95, Windows 98, and LAN Manager.*
- **CN:** A displayable version of the user's name
- **objectGUID:** An identifier for a user or group that won't change. Important as users will change their username if their surname changes.

So, I think **SamAccountName == User.Identity.Name**, but the docs say that SamAccountName is for earlier operating systems. Does this effectively mean this is deprecated and I should be using something else?

Also, are my assertions about CN and objectGUID correct?

Comment: Are you using Windows Authentication to get your user identity?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: Can you also add the purpose of using AD groups? Is it to restrict pages access for example?

Comment: The app is basically a task system where different people in the org will be able to see and/or mark tasks as complete based on the AD groups they are in. AD Groups are managed by a different part of the org and the same AD groups are also used by different systems.

Comment: Ok I will provide an answer in a few minutes ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First step: setting the parameters to use AD:**

In your the  section of your web.config file, set the following:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
   <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
          name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
          applicationName="/" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Now, you will be able to directly use methods from the System.Web.Security namespace.

**If you want to restrict the access to a View to only people members of the "groupName" group of your AD:**

You only have to decorate your controller action like that:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\groupName")]
Public ActionResult Index()
{...}
```

**If you want to do treatments based on the AD groups of users:**

Use methods such as "IsInRole(rolename)" in your treatments:

```
if (User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\groupName"))
{
     // Do what you want
}
```

EDIT: implementation of the problematic: here you should save the sAMAccountName of the group affected to your task when you create the task. Then when a user wants to mark the task as complete, just check:

```
if (User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\" + sAMAccountNameOfTheGroupDedicatedToYourTask))
{
     // Mark as complete
}
```

Comment: I won't know the group names at compile time. I'm querying active directory for a full list and then the user selects one that will get saved against their new task. That's why I want to know what all the AD fields mean. What is SamAccountName and is that what I should use when using User.IsInRole(x)?

Comment: try using Roles.GetRolesForUser() method to get the list (after having done the 1st step previously described). It's using the role provider you specified so will be using the AD.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ak75t41.aspx

Comment: If you can quickly test Roles.GetRolesForUser(). I will also look into old sources where I made group listing to try to help you if it's not working.

Sorry for the quick edit, but can you also provide the way you see your implementation, step by step? Like 'display the page => user clicks on a task to mark as complete => check ...'

Comment: When the user selects a role for a task, it might not be a role they are in. I have code that gets a full list of AD groups, but I'm not sure how these AD details maps to Identity details.

Comment: Ok... So obviously not the good answer as I did not understand the role he can select is not necessary one he has. I will look into my old code to check the solution. It's using DirectoryEntry..

But you may have problems to filter the groups because you will get all the AD groups, not only for your current use... do they have a name template to get only the groups that have to be displayed to select?

Comment: I think that's my fault. My question is not as clear as I wanted it to be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45907/discussion-between-nicolas-r-and-richard)