# MVC Authentication/Authorization with Active Directory in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, active-directory, iis-express

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1894061.aspx?ASP+NET+MVC+integration+with+Active+Directory](http://forums.asp.net/t/1894061.aspx?ASP%20NET%20MVC%20integration%20with%20Active%20Directory)

In regards to the post above.

I have been trying to implement Active Directory Security using IIS Express for my local development enviornment using Visual Studio 2013. Currently I have modified the IIS Express to allow me to override the authentication methods in the applicationhost.config.  As specified in this post

[IIS Express Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication)

In addtion, I also made the default applicationpool user a valid Domain Administrator.   I modified the Authorize attribute on the Home Controller of a basic MVC Site.  Then on the home controller added the following code, as suggested in the first post I mentioned.  The code is below.   When I browse to this page It only shows the groups of the local machine that I belong to.  It does not show the groups of the Domain that I belong to.  Because of this I cannot actually Authorize any groups on my Domain only groups that exist locally.  Why is that?  Any assistance would be helpful.

```
<h2>Logged in as: @User.Identity.Name</h2>
<h2>Groups</h2>
<ul>
@{
    var id = User.Identity as System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;
    foreach(var g in id.Groups)
    {
        var name = g.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value;
        var nameWithoutAuthority = name;
        var idx = name.IndexOf('\\');
        if (idx >= 0)
        {
            nameWithoutAuthority = name.Substring(idx + 1);
        }
        <li>@g.Value,
            @name,
            @User.IsInRole(name),
            @nameWithoutAuthority,
            @User.IsInRole(nameWithoutAuthority)
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Out of interest are you logged into your local computer on a domain account or are you logged in as a local user? Just wondering if that maybe the issue.

Comment: Im logged in as a domain account and that domain account is a domain administrator.  I doubt that this is an issue.

Comment: What is the full @User.Identity.Name displaying on the web page i.e. does it include your full domain? It feels like you are not in as a domain user.

Comment: This existing stackoverflow post looks promising: [Configure aps.net mvc for AD authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279140/configure-asp-net-mvc-for-authentication-against-ad). This is a different approach that doesn't involve editing your IISExpress applicationconfig. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305301/mapping-user-identity-in-net-mvc-app-to-active-directory-user) adds some more config in which may be worth trying. [This post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1450589.aspx?ASP+Windows+authentication+Authorziation+not+working+for+Active+Directory+groups) I dont like

Comment: @sarin  I have tired all these things.

Comment: What do you get if you try the fully qualified reference to the current request context: var id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity; or var id = Controller.Request.LogonUserIdentity;

Comment: I actually get a valid Domain User Domain\somesuer.... but the groups are not working

Comment: Is your web server joined to the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing would appear to be by design, see [Which Groups Does WindowsIdentity.Groups Return?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2008/02/07/which-groups-does-windowsidentity-groups-return.aspx)

To summarise

> Under the covers, WindowsIdentity populates the groups collection by querying Windows for information on the groups that the user token is
> a member of.  However, before returning this list, **the Groups property
> filters out some of the returned groups**.
>
> Specifically, any groups which were on the token for deny-only will
> not be returned in the Groups collection.  Similarly, a group which is
> the SE_GROUP_LOGON_ID will not be returned.
>
> ...If you want to retrieve all of the groups however, there's not an easy built-in way for you to do this.  Instead, you'll have to P/Invoke to the GetTokenInformation API to retrieve the groups yourself.

```
public static void Main()
{
    using (WindowsIdentity currentIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
    {               
        var groups = // Get all of the groups from our account, and translate them from IdentityReferences to NTAccounts  
                    from groupIdentity in currentIdentity.Groups
                    where groupIdentity.IsValidTargetType(typeof(NTAccount))
                    select groupIdentity.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount into ntAccounts

                    // Sort the NTAccounts by their account name
                    let domainName = ntAccounts.GetDomainName()
                    let groupName = ntAccounts.GetAccountName()
                    orderby domainName

                    // Group the sorted accounts by the domain they belong to, and sort the grouped groups by domain name
                    group ntAccounts by domainName into domainGroups
                    orderby domainGroups.Key
                    select domainGroups;

        foreach (var domainGroups in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Groups from domain: {0}", domainGroups.Key);

            foreach (var group in domainGroups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    {0}", group.GetAccountName());
            }
        }
    }
}

private static string GetDomainName(this NTAccount account)
{
    string[] split = account.Value.Split('\\');
    return split.Length == 1 ? String.Empty : split[0];
}

private static string GetAccountName(this NTAccount account)
{
    string[] split = account.Value.Split('\\');
    return split[split.Length - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was quite helpful.